# Better precision but identical functionality to a double in .Net

Tags: .net, math, precision

I've written a simple mandelbrot fractal generator (pretty pics available upon request :)

The problem I'm running into is that when I "zoom in" far enough, the image starts to pixelate. After a bit of investigation, this seems to be caused by hitting the precision limit of the double type used by `System.Numerics.Complex` to store the real and imaginary values used in my calculations.

Is there any other type I can use or another way to gain greater precision (presumably at the expense of more memory)

Failing that, is there an easy way I can determine the maximum precision of a double and disable zoom functionality if the zoom would result in pixelation?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: You should review your algorithms. There is a package [fractint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractint), which was able to render fractals using only integer calculations (at least in the older versions).

Comment: @Vlad I know Fractint - It's actually what prompted me to write my own generator. I wasn't aware it used only integers but the barrier I'm hitting is with my bounding complex numbers - If I want to examine the fractal between (say) `-0.2-0.1i` and `0.2+0.1i`, how can I do so using integers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using the [BigNum](http://www.fractal-landscapes.co.uk/bigint.html) library for C#, or any other [Arbitrary-precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) arithmetic library.

Comment: I've been developing for years and never come across BigNum - I suppose it's more useful for mathematical problems than business logic :) I'll accept as soon as the 10-min timeout is up.

Answer (score 4):

Use [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

It is twice the `double` in precision (16 bytes instead of 8)

Comment: It will take longer, but you'll still hit the wall of precision limits eventually

Comment: Thanks, I've never had much use for decimal before - I can now see a use for it.

Comment: @sinelaw Decimal must surely have enough precision for his use.

Comment: @Aliostad - Thank you for your reply, I'll probably end up using decimal initially as it's easier to implement than BigNum but it seems BigNum is what I'm after. The reason for this is that I can zoom in to a fractal an infinite number of times and still get useful results. A limit of PC memory > a limit of 16 bits.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure - zooming in fractals can require a lot of precision bits

Comment: I'd guess you can zoom in about twice as much(assuming exponential zoom) before it starts to pixelate with `Decimal`.